# JavaScript function href

Tags: javascript, html

I'm creating a function in `javascript` that is activated by an `onclick` and I just need a simple line of `javascipt` code to link to another html page.

```
<area shape="rect" coords="78,348,182,395" onclick="nextquestion">
```

user clicks on that area

```
function nextquestion(){
   window.location="contact.html";
}
```

links to this function

Comment: `onclick="nextquestion();"`

Comment: `<area shape="rect" coords="78,348,182,395" href="contact.html">` would be a whole lot easier.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't use `<area .... href="" />`? Href is valid for area tag

Answer (score 1):

You are not executing the function in this code:

```
<area shape="rect" coords="78,348,182,395" onclick="nextquestion">
```

`nextquestion` only stays there as a unused variable pointing to the function.

Use `nextquestion()` to actually execute the function:

```
<area shape="rect" coords="78,348,182,395" onclick="nextquestion()">
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd want to change your onclick to *call* the function, in JS this requires a set of parentheses after the *name* of the function like:

`<area shape="rect" coords="78,348,182,395" onclick="nextquestion();">`

Then in your JS

```
function nextquestion() {
    window.location.href = 'contact.html';
}
```

Comment: Also window.location = "contact.html"; works and window.location.href = "contact.html"; is a synonym (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location).

Answer (score 0):

did you try this ?

```
<area shape="rect" coords="78,348,182,395" href = 'contact.html'>
```

or

```
<area shape="rect" coords="78,348,182,395" onclick="nextquestion()">
```